# How I can convert a html string to pdf?

Tags: html, asp-classic, pdf-generation

I am using ASPPDF active x component. I have already create a pdf document from ASP. But the content of this pdf is only simple text. How I can convert asp variable, that contains html tags, to pdf document?

here is my code

```
Set Pdf = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Pdf")                
Set Doc = Pdf.CreateDocument                    
Doc.Title = "Mi primer documento PDF"
Doc.Creator = "arsys.es"                    
Set Page  = Doc.Pages.Add                   
Set Font =  Doc.Fonts("Helvetica")          
Params = "x=0; y=650; width=612; alignment=center;  size=10"                    
Page.Canvas.DrawText "pdf text", Params, Font 'can I put asp variable instead of "pdf      text"?                   
Filename = Doc.Save( Server.MapPath("salida\archivo.pdf"), False  )                 
Response.Write "Enhorabuena! Descarga tu primer <A HREF=salida/" &  Filename &  ">archivo  PDF</A>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same thing running on my server.  The guide that comes with it requires you to use `Doc.ImportFromUrl` but that will need an full reference to the ASP page. So....

1) Create your ASP page and layout your page with SQL and bindings if required. I use this with a QueryString parameter as I only want to reference one value to create the PDF.....my example is based around creating an invoice.

2) In a "different folder" to your ASP page run the ASPPDF script in a page

3) Ensure you have a full reference to the path e.g. http://www.domain.com/file.asp

This should help:

```
<%
Set Pdf = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Pdf")
Set Doc = Pdf.CreateDocument
' A4 paper size - if US required remove/comment the line below.
Set Page = Doc.Pages.Add(595.3, 841.9) 
Doc.ImportFromUrl "http://www.yourdomain.com/yourfile.asp?valueID=" & Request.QueryString("valueID")

Filename = Doc.Save( Server.MapPath("quotation.pdf"), False ) 
    'Response.Write "Success! Download your PDF file <A HREF="Filename & ">here</A>

%>
```

That works for me anyway!